# Network card on XP non retrieval IP, subnet and DNS

Tags: windows-xp, networking

The network card of a PC with Windows XP, does not receive addresses from the router, or subnet, or the DNS. The new card I installed has the same problem, and the wireless works fine. What could be the cause, and how you could solve?

Comment: Sanity check: Is there a network cable plugged into the card?  Does that cable (and by implication the outlet behind it) work on other PCs?

Comment: I tried it with more than one cable ... to no avail. The cable is connected to Windows, I do not receive and send data.

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel -> Open Network Connections -> Right click on your active LAN or Internet connection and select Properties.

In the General tab, in the box in the middle, highlight the Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) item, and click Properties.

If it is a static address, this could be why, change it to Obtain and IP Automatically (same for DNS). If this page is blank then click on Advanced and see if DNS is coded in or if DHP is enabled or not.

If you make any changes, it may be best to reboot to see if it works or not.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested, both dalal old network card, which the new one after you have installed it, but nothing has changed. At this point I think the problem is Windows ...

Comment: If you ipconfig /all in CMD prompt does it say media disconnected?

Comment: From ipconfig /all, the media result connect...

Comment: It is not impossible not be incompatible with the router! Are you able to test a different router?

Comment: I changed the router just because I thought I depended on it ...

Comment: Can you use another device to get the subnet and default gateway, then give the machine a static IP?

Comment: Also, can it connect in safe mode with networking on.